# auto search using laravel and ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

how to create auto search in laravel . i have two table one is student another studentclass. From studentclass index file user pass student name now i need to check that student is exists or not in that studentclass where i am student_id in that table.
my Code:

```
<script>
     $('#stdname').keyup(function()
    {
      $.get('/stdClsByName/' + $(this).val())
      .success(function(data)
      {
        if(data)
        {
         for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
           var row = $("<tr><td>" + data[i].id + "</td></tr>");
         $("#stdsearch").append(row);
           console.log(data);
         }
        }
       else
        {
          alert('Please Enroll Student to the class first');
        }
      })
      .error(function ()
      {
        $("#stdsearch").append("Sorry there is no such record");
      })
    });
    </script>

Route::get('stdClsByName/{stdname}', 'studentclassesController@searchByName');
```

Controller:-

```
public function searchByName($stdnam){
    if ($stdnam){
        $name = $stdnam;
         $data = Student::
           where('name','LIKE', $name.'%')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get(array('id'));
           return Response::json($data);
            /*echo $data->id;
           if ($data) {
              $stdcls_stdid = Studentclass::where('student_id',$data)->get('student_id');
           return Response::json($stdcls_stdid);
           }*/
   }
    return Response::json(false);
}
```

controller file is not working please help on that code. where i need first check all the student name from student table after that is that student`is in studentclass or not if so than send json file. using like cluse...

Comment: controller file is not working means getting any error?